# React Native: Is it better to initiate loading a screen's resources before or after navigating to screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In my React Native app, I have `screenA` that has a button that takes me to `screenB`. `screenB` requires data that has to be fetched from a server via the API call (`this.props.fetchData(param1, param2)`. I have `param1` and `param2` on `screenA`.

Right now, the way I'm doing it is that I pass `param1` and `param2` as navigation parameters from `screenA` to `screenB`, then when `screenB` mounts, I call `this.props.fetchData`.

So the code I have is:

*screenA*

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB', {param1, param2});
```

*screenB*

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchData(this.props.navigation.state.params.param1, this.props.navigation.state.params.param2);
}
```

**What I Want To Know:**

Would there be any reason to call `this.props.fetchData()` from `screenA` instead? The resources get saved in the Redux store, so they're accessible from `screenB` no matter where I load them from. My code would look like this:

*screenA*

```
this.props.fetchData(param1, param2);
this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB', {param1, param2});
```

*screenB*

```
<nothing>
```

The advantage I can imagine to this is that since it takes a finite amount of time to navigate to `screenB`, if I initiated loading the resources just before navigating to it, the user wouldn't have to wait as long on `screenB` before the resources load. The *disadvantage* is that in the event that the call to navigate to `screenB` doesn't work, the resources are loaded for nothing.

Does anyone know of any reasons to choose one approach over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some shortcomings that can occur on calling API on screen A:

1. In case screen B is opened from another screen C, then in that case you have to again do the API call on screen C and pass the data.
2. If somehow due to slow internet connection, API takes long time then it may show the incorrect state on Screen B for a while and may be later update it.
3. It could happen that screen A could unmount upon navigation, while the API call is on its way, in such a case it could happen that you never get the updated props on screen B since screen A was already unmounted.

You may see that if these scenarios are fine for you, than you may proceed with your approach of calling API on screen A.

Comment: This is great advice, thanks. #1 makes sense, because even though I navigate to `screenB` only via `screenA` at the moment, making the API call from `screenB` keeps the possibility open to navigate to it from other screens in the future. #2 doesn't apply to my situation because I have a loading indicator, but this would be valid on any screen where I don't have one. #3 I've never run into, but I'm glad you pointed it out. I'll stick with the original approach in case this does ever happen. Thanks again!

Comment: Its great to hear that the answer helped you. Thanks :) . You may accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: It makes me wait x number of minutes before I can accept ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would not make the navigation navigate method dependent on an API call. The most important Stores would be loaded on initial app start. What if you load the data for screen b directly on start of the screen a? If the data is available via the Redux then I don't prefer to pass params trough navigate.

Comment: For sure, I agree. For this app, `screenA` contains a list of items, and clicking one of them takes you to `screenB`, where `screenB` will display info for that clicked item. So `param1` and `param2` are determined when you click the item, so unfortunately I can't load them when `screenA` loads. But yes, I agree with everything you said there in general.